# How to start and stop Electron application from NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, launching-application

I am working on a NodeJs application which helps the developers in my company with the development of our Electron-based product. It does some automatization and at the end, it starts the Electron-app automatically.

Starting the Electron app from inside NodeJs is not a problem. normally the apps are started with a bash script which looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOME=$PWD/home-dir ./node_modules/.bin/electron myAppDir
```

`myAppDir` is the directory with my Electron-App, could be a *JavaScript* file as well.

Worth to mention, that `./node_modules/.bin/electron` is just a symlink to `./node_modules/electron/cli.js`

I did following:

```
const app = execFile('/the/path/to/the/bash/script', [], {
            windowsHide: true,
        },(error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            warn('The app was terminated');
        });
```

This starts the app just fine. However if I do `app.kill('SIGTERM');` it outputs the **'The app was terminated'** but the app itself does not close.

I tried to execute the `node_modules/.bin/electron` or the `./node_modules/electron/cli.js` instead:

```
const app = execFile('/the/path/to/node_modules/.bin/electron', ['myAppDir'], {
            windowsHide: true,
            detached: true,
            env: {
                HOME: 'path/to/home'),
            }
```

I can launch the Electron app but again - it does not close the running app when I do `app.kill('SIGTERM');`

**EDIT:**

My assumption is, that the electron launcher actually spawns a new subprocess, thus killing the launcher does not stops the actual launched app.

This is the content of `./node_modules/.bin/electron` (or `./node_modules/electron/cli.js` respectively)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var electron = require('./')

var proc = require('child_process')

var child = proc.spawn(electron, process.argv.slice(2), {stdio: 'inherit'})
child.on('close', function (code) {
  process.exit(code)
})
```

Comment: Did you try ‘app.quit()’?

Comment: Then I get `TypeError: app.quit is not a function`

Comment: You can do this from inside an electron app. I just start an electron app from an NodeJs script.

Comment: "I tried to execute the node_modules/.bin/electron" I couldn't with your code. The only thing worked for me was `execFile('node',
  ['path/to/electron/cli.js', './myapp.js']` and it quits for kill successfully.

Comment: The `./myapp.js` was the `param1` Parameter in the original question, I edited my question so it is more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library in you node app https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation and with its .processes(cb) method find running electron app and kill it in the callback of the processes method.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would accept this just as a workaround. It has to be possible to start and stop one NodeJs Application from within another NodeJs application without needing to deal with thePIDs.